# Get ALL post ID's export list (Only id's. Php or sql not important )

Tags: posts, sql, id, export

please help me. I dont know How can I do. I need list all posts IDs. export need

1
3
5
6
7
8
9
.
.
.
.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to get all IDs. Assuming you do want all posts - which include Posts, Pages, Media, Menu Items, custom post types, etc.:

phpMyAdmin:

Run a SQL query: `SELECT ID FROM wp_posts`
then export the results to whatever file type you prefer.

Comment: thanks too much. I try most code but list more details. This is easy and very usefull